# EventBot: subscribing activity is not reached by Event

Tags: android, interface, callback, fragment, event-bus

**Problem:**
For some communication scenarios I am using [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).
I have got an event that is already successfully fired and subscribed by different components in my app. 
Now I need an `activity` to subscribe that event. Unfortunately it is not reached.

**Question:**
How can I achieve that the `activity` does subscribe the event correctly, either? Is the problem with registering the `activity`?

**Note:**
I have found that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29236704/which-activity-lifecycle-methods-are-best-to-register-unregister-to-event-bus) that suggests to use onStart() and onStop() events.

my activity class:

```
public class MachineActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

  (...)

  @Override
  protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
  }

  @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
  public void characteristicsChangeByUser(IntentChangeByUser intentChangeByUser) {
    // Do something here.
  }

  (...)
}
```

EventBus class:

```
public class IntentChangeByUser {

  int position;
  int value;

  public IntentChangeByUser(int position, int value){
    this.position = position;
    this.value = value;
  }

  public int getPosition() {
    return position;
  }

  public int getValue() {
    return value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be because you have the wrong way to unregister then EventBus in `onStop()`.
Change to this:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
   EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    super.onStop();
}
```

Then make sure in your Subscriber Activity, there is received Event:

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void characteristicsChangeByUser(IntentChangeByUser intentChangeByUser) {
  // Do something here.
  Log.d("Activity", "IntentChangeByUser Event received");
}
```